# Stringify a string or null?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm storing data as JSON objects in `localStorage`, because sometimes it can be an array, and I can just store values there.

I have a key, where the value can be an array, or null. `JSON.stringify()` to set, and `JSON.parse()` to get works perfect.

But I have a key where the value can be a string, or null. It causes problems. If I don't stringify and parse it, it stores `null` as `"null"`, which is a truthy value.

If I do, it throws error when the value is originally a string. As I see, if I try to stringify a string, nothing happens, that's why.

Of course I could use `==` (equal value) as comparison, and to not stringify and parse to solve the problem, but I'm looking for something more elegant.

Any ideas?

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({a: null}))` correctly serializes and deserializes the `null` as `null` and not a string. Same with `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(null))`. Why exactly does it not deserialize in your case?

Comment: Read the description again. `null` becomes `"null"` just if I just `setItem()` and `getItem()` it from `localStorage`, without `JSON` methods. The problem is with `JSON.stringify(JSON.parse("asd"))`. The problem is not with `null`, but with parsing a string.

Comment: Wait, why are you stringifying each *value*? Shouldn't you do `getItem` -> `parse` entire item -> add another entry -> `stringify` entire item -> `setItem`? That should be how this happens and `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify("abc"))` works as does `localStorage.setItem("test", JSON.stringify("abc"));JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("test"))`. And it works the same whether the value is a string, `null`, an array or an object.

Answer (score 1):

If you always use `JSON.parse` to read the value you store in the localStorage, then you will be able to retrieve a `null` value and not a `"null"` string.

Here is an example:

```
function set(value) {
  window.localStorage.test = JSON.stringify(value);
}
function get() {
  return JSON.parse(window.localStorage.test);
}

set(null);
console.log(get()); //Output: null (null value)

set("null");
console.log(get()); //Output: "null" (the string)
```